# how to send mail from gmail smtp server by using the ssis

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm just getting into sql-server SSIS, so forgive me if this is a basic question. Use the SSISwant to send mail from  gmail smtp server.

```
Smtp host =smtp.gmail.com 
port=587 ,
From_Mail_ID=xyz@gmail.com,
To_Mail_ID=abc@gmail.com,
```

Using the above information I want to send mail from SSIS. How do I use SSIS to do this?

If have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in task for sending SMTP mail in SSIS.  If you want to use a script task to send mail via SMTP the post below lists several ways to do what you are looking to do.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8

Comment: Jason Cumberland Thanks for reply,need helping hand on script task,plz show some syntax or helpful example on script task to send mail .

Comment: @shamim http://sriharik.blogspot.com/2008/08/sending-email-through-ssis-script-task.html That should work in SSIS 2005, since you're limited to VB.NET only.

Comment: Here's a VB.Net example.  http://pragmaticworks.com/help/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20send%20HTML%20email%20in%20SSIS.htm

Answer (score 1):

As Jason Pointed out, that to send email using SSIS, you have to use Script Task.

Below links with scripts will help you out.

1. [Send Mail in SSIS using GMail](http://dwteam.in/send-mail-in-ssis-using-gmail/)
2. [Send Email from SSIS with option to indicate Email User and Password](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85172/Send-Email-from-SSIS-with-option-to-indicate-Email)